# How to format columns in xtable output

Tags: r

I have a data.frame DF and I'm using xtable to create an HTML table:

```
     Product    N° Clients     Capital (USD) Part. Capital (%) 
    1 A               536            2616925       33.62
    2 B               151            1613035       20.72
    3 c               112            1007983       12.95
```

The problem is that when generating the html:

```
    DF.TAB <- xtable(DF, align = "cccrc",latex.environments="center", format.args = list(digits = 2, format = c("s","d","d","d","f"), big.mark = ","), floating = FALSE)
    print(DF.TAB,type = "html", include.rownames=FALSE, file = "DF.TAB.html")
```

I expect some columns (Part. Capital) to have two decimal places (even if some elements may be integers) and comma separator "," and for other columns to be treated as integers but the result is not this way:

```
     Product       N° Clients    Capital (USD) Part. Capital (%) 
    1 A               536          2616925.00       33.62
    2 B               151          1613035.00       20.72
    3 c               112          1007983.00       12.95
```

BTW, I had to align and format an "invisible" column because without that I couldn't get it work.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
DF[,3]<-format(as.numeric(DF[,3]),big.mark=",")
DF.TAB <- xtable(DF, align = "cccrc",latex.environments="center", format.args = list(digits = 2, format = c("d","d","s","f")))
print(DF.TAB,type = "html", include.rownames=FALSE, file = "DF.TAB.html")
```

In `R` this results in

```
     Product N° Clients Capital (USD) Part. Capital (%)
[1,] "A"     "536"      "2,616,925"   "33.62"          
[2,] "B"     "151"      "1,613,035"   "20.72"          
[3,] "c"     "112"      "1,007,983"   "12.95"
```

The HTML version looks like this:[image]

Comment: I tested it now. It works with xtable and as HTML output with the code snippet you have posted.

Comment: You're right but dont' forget that it's also important that the final output shows big comma and no decimals in "Capital" (2,616,925) and two decimal always in "Part Capital" (33.62)

Comment: If you want the special character in "N° Clients" to be displayed correctly in the HTML version, I suggest that you edit the HTML file and replace the`°` character with `&deg`.